# Printing 2D array in matrix format

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array as follows:

```
long[,] arr = new long[4, 4] {{ 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                              { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                              { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                              { 1, 1, 1, 1 }};
```

I want to print the values of this array in matrix format like:

```
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do it like this (with a slightly modified array to show it works for non-square arrays):

```
        long[,] arr = new long[5, 4] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, { 3, 3, 3, 3 }, { 4, 4, 4, 4 } };

        int rowLength = arr.GetLength(0);
        int colLength = arr.GetLength(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", arr[i, j]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Instead of "\n" you could use Environment.NewLine, this is recomended and always works

Comment: You don't need `string.Format` there, it could be simplified as `Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i, j]);`

Comment: I have error `Wrong number of indices inside []`. Solution is `arr[i][j]`

Answer (score 9):

like so:

```
long[,] arr = new long[4, 4] { { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };

var rowCount = arr.GetLength(0);
var colCount = arr.GetLength(1);
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)               
        Console.Write(String.Format("{0}\t", arr[row,col]));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: you need to left-pad numbers so that columns align

Comment: That won't put spaces between the digits.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile on my computer in VS2010

Answer (score 8):

I wrote extension method

```
public static string ToMatrixString<T>(this T[,] matrix, string delimiter = "\t")
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();

    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            s.Append(matrix[i, j]).Append(delimiter);
        }

        s.AppendLine();
    }

    return s.ToString();
}
```

To use just call the method

```
results.ToMatrixString();
```

Comment: This is the answer that makes this a method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in **Unity**:

(Modified answer from @markmuetz so be sure to [upvote his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12827010/3324388))

```
int[,] rawNodes = new int[,]
{
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};

private void Start()
{
    int rowLength = rawNodes.GetLength(0);
    int colLength = rawNodes.GetLength(1);
    string arrayString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
        {
            arrayString += string.Format("{0} ", rawNodes[i, j]);
        }
        arrayString += System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }

    Debug.Log(arrayString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can do it like this in short hands.

```
        int[,] values=new int[2,3]{{2,4,5},{4,5,2}};

        for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < values.GetLength(1); k++) {
                Console.Write(values[i,k]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: What about the spaces between the array element. This does to diff rows.

Comment: We can not see spaces between values in the expected answer in the question, Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this also

```
        long[,] arr = new long[4, 4] { { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }};

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i,j]+" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a square matrix:

```
    int[,] mat = new int[,]{{ 1, 0, 0 },{ 0, 1, 0},{ 0, 0, 1}};
    int i=1;
    foreach(int e in mat){
        Console.Write(i%Math.Sqrt(mat.Length)==0? $"{e}\n" : e);
        i+=1;
    }
```