# How do i get a character in a given coordinate in the C# console?

Tags: c#, windows, console-application

I'm trying to make a roguelike in C#, and i got to make a little map, and a loop that checks if w/s/a/d is pressed to move the player; but **i have a problem detecting walls**; let's say i want to know if there is a wall to the right before moving there, **i get the player position, i check what is on the right of that position, and if it's a '#', i don't let the player move because it's supposed to be a wall.**

But here's the problem, in the console, **how do i check if the coordinate, for instance "(15,2)" contains a '#' char?**

Is there an easier way to check if a given coordinate contains that character?

**And how? Because i tried, but i can't GET the char in a certain coord of the console.**

Something like:

```
static bool wallcheck_x(int xpos) {
        xpos++;
        //Now, it should GET the char allocated in xpos++;
        if (/*char that's in xpos++ */ == '#')
        {
            return true; //it's a wall
        }
        return false; //it's not a wall
    }
```

Comment: Don't rely on checking the screen to determine the state of your game.  Instead, represent the map in some kind of structure (array?) and check that instead.

Comment: *this is also an answer to gleng* 
The problem is, that this thing i'm trying to create is way too simple, the map is just like a set of Console.writeLine calls with "########", "#......#", etc...
But, let's say i did the map in a multidimensional array... **then how do i print the array in the console**?

Comment: @SamuelMuñoz See my edit to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing it that way. You should have something that maps to what is displayed in the console, I assume that's how you even see the map to begin with. When a player moves, you should check it based on your map, *not* what is displayed in the console.

So for example...

> how do i check if the coordinate, for instance "(15,2)" contains a '#' char?

Don't check what's in the console at (15,2), but check your map that *displays* what's in the console for a `#` instead. It's much easier that way.

> But, let's say i did the map in a multidimensional array... then how do i print the array in the console?

Use Google, man. Here's what I pulled from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826760/printing-2d-array-in-matrix-format):

```
int rowLength = arr.GetLength(0);
int colLength = arr.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", arr[i, j]));
    }
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

What this does is traverses the array by row, printing each character in the row. When it reaches the end of a row, it prints a new line and begins printing the new row. Your array would probably be a 2-dimensional character array which represents the map. Likewise, you can keep track of a player's position with something like:

```
int playerXPos;
int playerYPos;
```

You would need to update those as your character moves. So, credit to gleng for this snippet, you can check if the player has hit a wall:

```
if (arr[playerXPos, playerYPos] == '#')
{
     // player has collided with a wall
}
else
{
     // player has NOT collided with a wall
}
```

Though it would be more scalable to have an actual Player data structure, this seems like it would suit you just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped. I'm going to make it in a multidimensional array. And yeah, i should have googled it, but i didn't think about it because it was just a comment :D
Thanks to you too, gleng.

Comment: @SamuelMuñoz Don't forget that your player positions will be zero-based from the **top and left-most** corner of your map. Happy coding

Comment: Yep, same as the console default coordinates. Happy coding to you too! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without having access to any of your code (you should really post it for help like this), i'm assuming you would do something like:

```
if (map[player.X, player.Y] == '#')
{
     // player has collided with a wall
}
else
{
     // player has NOT collided with a wall
}
```

This code assumes that `map` is a multidimensional array that contains your map.