# How to insert words of sentences into a matrix?

Tags: asp.net, string, text, vector

Hello I am trying to calculate cosine similarity between sentences with the given array that consist 5 words.So ı have an asp.net project where I wrote the code to calculate the top 5 words(by frequency) out of a text(around 50-60 sentences) and I have these words in array K.Until here everything is ok.I would like to get each sentences from text(which is an input in my problem and there is a text area inapp where user an paste any text or article) and established the vectors.For example;
Lets assume that array

> ```
> K={technology, product,player}
> ```

and the given text is this;

> Apple Inc. is an American multinational technology company
>   headquartered in Cupertino, California, that designs, develops, and
>   sells consumer electronics, computer software, and online services.
>   Its hardware products include the iPhone smartphone, the iPad tablet
>   computer, the Mac personal computer, the iPod portable media player,
>   and the Apple Watch smartwatch. Apple's consumer software includes the
>   OS X and iOS operating systems, the iTunes media player, the Safari
>   web browser, and the iLife and iWork creativity and productivity
>   suites. Its online services include the iTunes Store, the iOS App
>   Store and Mac App Store, and iCloud.

so four vectors for four sentences should be like this

> s1={1,0,0} s2={0,1,1} s3={0,0,1} s4={0,0,0}

How can i establish these vector on asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following [SQL LIKE method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417070/c-sharp-version-of-sql-like) and a [Print2DArray method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094093/how-to-print-2d-array-to-console-in-c-sharp). If you absolutely need to use arrays

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] keywords = {...}; // your keywords
        string text = "..."; // your text

        string[] textInArray = text.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int[,] vectors = new int[textInArray.Length, keywords.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < textInArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] words = textInArray[i].Split(' ');
            for (int j = 0; j < keywords.Length; j++)
            {
                foreach (var word in words)
                {
                    if (Like(word, "%"+keywords[j]+"%"))
                    {
                        vectors[i, j]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Print2DArray(vectors);
    }
```

Keep in mind, the SQL like method I use makes "products" a version of "product" and ups the counter, but it makes "productivity" a version of "product" as well. It splits Apple Inc. as a sentence. **You need to fine tune this, as it is a VERY BASIC version of what you want to accomplish.** You could use dictionary of string and int array, or even a struct to get this done more elegantly, but the basics are the same.

I am here for further questions!

Comment: First,thank you so much for your very helpful answer.which library should i add to my code to be able to use Like and Print2DArray methods?

Comment: I have used these to library using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient; using System.Data.Linq; and  as a method I have used  if ( SqlMethods.Like(word, "%"+keywords[j]+"%")) this however I got this error saying "Method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' cannot be used on the client; it is only for translation to SQL."

Comment: How ever when I use this instead of Like it worked if (word.Contains (keywords[j]))

Comment: I have given links to other stackoverflow questions containing said methods (first line of my answer), but I did not think of string.Contains() . Great idea !