# Outputting 2-dimensional arrays to the Console

Tags: c#, arrays

First up I wanted to create an "oldschool" boardgame in c# using the console.

I already made a 2 Dimensional Arrays consisting of the fields i wanted the console to Show as board where you can move your "hero".

```
Feld[,] result = new Feld[,] {
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null },
    {new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.LINKS) },
    {new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN) },
    {new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.LINKS)  },
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.OBEN),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null  },
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.UNTEN),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,null,null,null   },
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,null,null,null   },
    {null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,null   },
    {null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,null,null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,null   },
    {null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.UNTEN),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.UNTEN),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.OBEN),new Feld(Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.LINKS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null   },
    {null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.UNTEN),null,null   },
    {new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.OBEN),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.UNTEN),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.OBEN),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.OBEN),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.UNTEN),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.OBEN),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.UNTEN)   },
    {new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.OBEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.OBEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.OBEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.OBEN),null,null,null,new Feld(Richtungen.UNTEN|Richtungen.OBEN)   },
    {new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.UNTEN,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.OBEN,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.UNTEN,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.OBEN|Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.UNTEN,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.OBEN,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS|Richtungen.UNTEN,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.RECHTS,false),new Feld(Richtungen.LINKS|Richtungen.OBEN,false) }
  };
```

Null being empty spaces and Feld (Richtungen.XYZ) meaning a Field with a Connection in the Direction written. (Richtungen.Oben = Connection in Direction.Up).

Now I encountered a Problem - I have no clue how to get my Array into a console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing 2D array in matrix format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826760/printing-2d-array-in-matrix-format)

Comment: doesn't this code hurt your eyes?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use two `For` loops to run through the array and use `Console.Write()` to draw the Board.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Feld[,] result = new Feld[,] { } ;

        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
            {
                if (result[x, y].IsFilled)
                {
                    Console.Write("x");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("O");
                }
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Feld
{
    public bool IsFilled { get; set; }
    public Feld(bool isFill)
    {
        IsFilled = isFill;
    }
}
```

Use `Properties` and `if` statements to decide what needs to be printed. Change the `100` values to the X and Y lengths of your array.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll try it out and try to write an exception for the null-values. 
If i read your Code correct those are not included and would throw an error or did i miss something?

Comment: Yes I didn't completely adhere to your code. If you wan't to change what the program draws you could check for nulls, this is just a general idea of how to draw your array. - Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for (int y = 0 y < result.GetLength(1); y++)
{  
  for (int x = 0 x < result.GetLength(0); x++)
  {
    Console.Write(result[x,y]?.ToString())
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: `result[x,y].ToString()` will throw an *exception* when `result[x,y]` return `null`

Comment: please add a comment, note etc. that you've used C# **6.0** syntax (C# 6.0 is stil not that popular)

Comment: you dont need `ToString` call. just remove it. `Write(object)` overload will be called and it will internally check for null and will then calls ToString.