# C# access row in jagged array mixed with multiple dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to simply access the `ith` row by using `street[i]`.

```
    int[][,] street = new int[7][,] { 
        new int [,] { {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
        new int [,] { {0, 1 }, {0, -1} }, 
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {1, 0} },
        new int [,] { {1, 0 }, {0, -1} }, 
        new int [,] { {1, 0 }, {0, 1} }, 
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {0, -1} }, 
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {0, 1} }, 
    };
    System.Console.WriteLine(street[0]); # print out System.Int32[,]
```

I expected to get `[[0,0], [0,0]]`, but threw out `System.Int32[,]`. Why?

Comment: It's because the (default) `ToString()` displays the typename.

Comment: Look here: [Array.ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245581/array-tostring)

Comment: What you want look like a json serialisation un indented. So you can just do that. Print the result of the serialisation of the object.

Comment: you can use a json serializer and print the serialized object like @DragandDrop says, let me do an example for you.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know it will call `ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of iterating over the 2D array at the `ith` row using [GetUpperBound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netframework-4.8), and also outputting the 2D array as a single string using a helper function:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[][,] street = new int[7][,] {
        new int [,] { {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
        new int [,] { {0, 1 }, {0, -1} },
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {1, 0} },
        new int [,] { {1, 0 }, {0, -1} },
        new int [,] { {1, 0 }, {0, 1} },
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {0, -1} },
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {0, 1} },
    };

    System.Console.WriteLine("Accessing each element individually:");
    int rowNumber = 3;
    int[,] row = street[rowNumber]; // access the ith rowNumber
    for(int r = 0; r <= row.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= row.GetUpperBound(1); c++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("[" + rowNumber + "][" + r + ", " + c + "] = " + row[r, c]);
        }
    }


    System.Console.WriteLine("\r\nOutputting the 2D array as a single string via a helper function:");
    System.Console.WriteLine("Row " + rowNumber + " = " + GetRow(rowNumber, street));

    System.Console.Write("\r\nPress Enter to Quit...");
    System.Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string GetRow(int row, int[][,] arr)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("[");
    int[,] arr2D = arr[row];
    int numRows = arr2D.GetUpperBound(0);
    for (int r = 0; r <= numRows; r++)
    {
        sb.Append("[");
        int rowLength = arr2D.GetUpperBound(1);
        for (int c = 0; c <= rowLength; c++)
        {
            sb.Append(arr2D[r, c] + ((c < rowLength) ? "," : ""));                    
        }
        sb.Append("]" + ((r < numRows) ? ", " : ""));
    }
    sb.Append("]");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Output:

```
Accessing each element individually:
[3][0, 0] = 1
[3][0, 1] = 0
[3][1, 0] = 0
[3][1, 1] = -1

Outputting the 2D array as a single string via a helper function:
Row 3 = [[1,0], [0,-1]]

Press Enter to Quit...
```

Comment: this answer totally differs from the required output in the question `[[0,0], [0,0]]`

Comment: And yet OP accepted -_-

Comment: @fubo I edited my answer to include the "required output".

Comment: @VictorWilson I edited my answer to include the "required output".

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the object and print the result.
I'm gonna use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) you can use any serializer you like.

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

And with your array created simply serialize the object and print that result.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
int[][,] street = new int[7][,] { 
        new int [,] { {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
        new int [,] { {0, 1 }, {0, -1} }, 
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {1, 0} },
        new int [,] { {1, 0 }, {0, -1} }, 
        new int [,] { {1, 0 }, {0, 1} }, 
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {0, -1} }, 
        new int [,] { {-1, 0 }, {0, 1} }, 
    };
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(street[0]));
//Or you can print all the array
//Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(street));
```

Comment: nice one approach +

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826760/printing-2d-array-in-matrix-format) answer here, how to iterate over a 2D array. I've modified the code for your question: https://dotnetfiddle.net/et9PFM

so replace

```
System.Console.WriteLine(street[0]); # print out System.Int32[,]
```

with

```
int rowLength = street[0].GetLength(0);
int colLength = street[0].GetLength(1);

Console.Write("[");
for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
{
    Console.Write("[");
    for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(street[0][i, j]);
        if (j < colLength - 1)
            Console.Write(",");
    }
    Console.Write("]");
    if (i < rowLength - 1)
        Console.Write(",");
}
Console.Write("]");
```